# I am unable to check the files available in the directory

Tags: python, unix, anaconda, subprocess, data-science

I am trying to read the csv files in the current directory. In-order to do that, I want to check all the files present in my current directory. I have tried doing it with check_output function. However, i received this error and I'm unable to figure out how to deal with it. This is the code I have tried:

```
from subprocess import check_output
print(check_output(["ls","../input"]).decode('utf8'))
```

this is the error i have received:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c18143c64098> in <module>
      1 from subprocess import check_output
----> 2 print(check_output(["ls","../input"]).decode('utf8'))

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    393 
    394     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 395                **kwargs).stdout
    396 
    397 

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    470         kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
    471 
--> 472     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    473         try:
    474             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    773                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    776         except:
    777             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1176                                          env,
   1177                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1178                                          startupinfo)
   1179             finally:
   1180                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: `os.listdir('../input')` but `"../input"` is not `current directory` and maybe this is your problem - you search in wrong folder.

Comment: maybe first check `..` to see if you have `input` in `..`

Comment: your error shows that you use Windows and I don't remeber if Windows has command `ls` or only `dir`. Better use `os.listdir()` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all the files in the current directory by doing this:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('./')
```

Comment: OP question is not how to list files bit why his code is not working properly.